# Detect click on the Collapsebutton in a TreeView

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a Treeview with nodes. If the user doubleclicks a node, an editdialog for the node opens where he can modify the data etc. 
There is a problem, if the user clicks fastly twice onto the collapsebutton of a node - this also counts a double click. Is there a way to avoid this? I searched the Web but i found nothing really helpfull. Detecting if the click is within a specific area is useless, cause the Treeview is dynamic and scrollable.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just call `HitTest` and find out where the user clicked.

```
private void treeView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hitTest = treeView1.HitTest(e.Location);
    if (hitTest.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.PlusMinus)
    { 
        //expand collapse clicked
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very very much. This works just perfect. In retrospect i would say im a bad googler... alway googled for "Collapse" or "Expand", but never thought about a simple "PlusMinus"

Comment: I should agree that this is hard to google, I tried but no good results :(