# What is a StateImage in a TreeView?

Tags: winforms

I have recently discovered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19226398/1169228) which allows me to identify if a user has clicked on a node or not. The `TreeViewHitTestInfo` returned by the `HitTest()` method contains a `Location` field of type [`TreeViewHitTestLocations`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeviewhittestlocations(v=vs.110).aspx) with the following flags:

```cs
public enum TreeViewHitTestLocations
{
    None = 1,
    Image = 2,
    Label = 4,
    Indent = 8,
    PlusMinus = 16,
    RightOfLabel = 32,
    StateImage = 64,
    AboveClientArea = 256,
    BelowClientArea = 512,
    RightOfClientArea = 1024,
    LeftOfClientArea = 2048,
}
```

This is what I found through testing:

[image: Screenshot]

```
None:         White
Image:        Green
Label:        Yellow
Indent:       Dark blue
PlusMinus:    Red
RightOfLabel: Light blue
```

The `ClientArea` flags are in light gray, but I haven't been able to identify the `StateImage` one. What is a StateImage?

Comment: It is the one you did not use.  Set the StateImageList property.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's meant for the CheckBox. Should've done some more testing. Thanks, @HansPassant.