# Detect click on the +/- button in a TreeView / Conversion of C# to Powershell

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell, treeview

I have a powershell script with a winform and a treeview.

Now I need to distinguish if a user clicked on the **name** of a winforms **treeview node** or on the **plus or minus** in front of the node.

If found this code:

```
private void treeView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hitTest = treeView1.HitTest(e.Location);
    if (hitTest.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.PlusMinus)
    { 
        //expand collapse clicked
    }
}
```

in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226171/detect-click-on-the-collapsebutton-in-a-treeview/19226398#19226398). I tried to translate it into Powershell (see below) and it seems to work... but: 
The problem is, wherever I click, the result is always "**indent**", which is one of the possible return values ([TreeViewHitTestLocations-Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeviewhittestlocations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))
But it should not be always the same, wherever I click.

```
$hitlocation = $treeview1.HitTest($treeview1.Location)
Write-Debug "$($hitlocation.location)"

if ($hitlocation.Location -eq [System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewHitTestLocations]::PlusMinus){ 
   # do stuff
   write-host "yes!"
}
```

So the question is, did i translate the code wrong, or is there another problem?

Comment: *What* is always **indent**?

Comment: Ahhh, problem is that you need to test the Location of the `EventArgs` object rather than the TreeView itself

Comment: could you maybe give me an example (in Powershell) on how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original example, the `HitTest()` is performed against the `Location` value carried by the `EventArgs` object that is passed along. In your example, you perform `HitTest()` against `$treeview1.Location`, which I assume to stay the same no matter where you click.

When you register the event action, define a parameter block with 2 parameters (for the `sender` and `e` arguments you see in the C# sample):

```
$treeview1.add_MouseDoubleClick({

    param($s,$e)

    # Now we can refer to $e like in the example
    $hitlocation = $treeview1.HitTest($e.Location)
    Write-Debug "$($hitlocation.Location)"

    if ($hitlocation.Location -eq [System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewHitTestLocations]::PlusMinus){ 
       # do stuff
       write-host "yes!"
    }
})
```

Comment: "Sender" in C# is always the object from which the event originated, right?

Comment: @Moss Correct, in this case the `$treeview1` object itself

Comment: You could also refer to the automatic `$Sender` and `$EventArgs` variables, but I personally like declaring the parameters like above

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!